# How to search millions of documents with an average of 8000 words each?

Tags: java, search, lucene, full-text-search, elasticsearch

I have an odd problem and I need some help on this.

I have a dataset of 6 million documents, composed of close to 8000 words each. Each word is always a number and words/numbers are separated by a whitespace.

After indexing all the data (I'm only indexing a subset for now) I need to perform queries by list of numbers but I only want documents that have **all** those numbers (the condition is AND).

I came up with this:

```
String [] codes_vec = ARRAY_WITH_500_STRINGS_ALL_NUMBERS;

BoolQueryBuilder qBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();

for (int i =0; i < codes_vec.length; ++i)
{

   qBuilder = qBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("code", codes_vec[i]));

}
```

The problem is, this seems to be very inefficient, how can I speed up the search ? Is there a better way of querying ElasticSearch that will be much faster in my case ?

Kind regards,
Zé Maria

Comment: Do you know what these 500 strings are beforehand?  Could you flag them in the index when they are created there?

Comment: how is your index organized?

Comment: Well the index is really simple, basically there's a document id + list of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a filter is likely to be faster than a match query.  Here's the documentation on boolean filters: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/bool-filter/

Here's how you could create and use one:

```
// create the filter
// to cache the results, add .cache(true);
BoolFilterBuilder filterBuilder = FilterBuilders.boolFilter();

// did you mean to skip the first one?
for (int i = 0; i < codes_vec.length; ++i)
    filterBuilder.must(FilterBuilders.termFilter("code", codes_vec[i]));

// add the filter to your search
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("index1")
            .setFilter(filterBuilder)
            .setFrom(0).setSize(10)
            .execute()
            .actionGet();
```

Comment: I'll try that for sure! One doubt regarding the setSize, is it similar to SQL's LIMIT parameter ?

Comment: Yes, size is the max number of results; use from to specify the starting point (so second page of 10 results would be from=10, size=10).  See http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/from-size/

Comment: Excelent results!! Much much faster :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Split the processing up in threads.  I would recommend using [Future](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html).

Comment: Thanks for the help, but you mean I should perform N queries each in it's own thread and filter the results manually ? Thanks in advance

Comment: How many threads you can create and use efficiently depends on your hardware.  If I am understanding correctly you have 500 queries... but I doubt 500 threads will help you :)  Maybe start with 10 threads and give each one 50 queries.  Collect them all at the end using the `get()` method of `Future`.  If you create 10 threads and there are 5 doing nothing, then decrease the number of threads created.

Comment: Well, it's not really 500 queries, I do have is a query with Y words and it should return all documents that have all those Y words.

Comment: In your for loop you are checking for documents that contain all your 500 words, but you are only checking one word at a time.  What I am suggesting is that you split it up into threads.  Each thread will still only check one word at a time, but you could have 10 threads all checking for one word at the same time.  Once all threads complete you will need to some how combine the results, discarding all documents that didn't match every word in every thread.